# Project upgraded to Meteor 1.7.0.5 won't start

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, npm

Reading https://blog.meteor.com/meteor-1-7-and-the-evergreen-dream-a8c1270b0901 and upgrading meteor, my project now won't start. I think it's related to some issues between ecmascript and babel.

I've run these commands:

```
meteor update
meteor npm install @babel/runtime@latest
meteor npm install meteor-node-stubs@latest
meteor reset
```

But the project won't start:

> /usr/local/bin/meteor --settings settings-development.json --port 3000
>   [[[[[
>   /media/martin/SSD240/dev/Proyectos-Full-Stack/proyecto-dinamo/dinamo-server-meteor
>   ]]]]]
>
> => Started proxy.
>   => Started MongoDB.
>   => Errors prevented startup:
>          While processing files with ecmascript (for target web.browser):
>
> /home/martin/.meteor/packages/ecmascript/.0.11.1.cvfkb8.l4wd++os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/plugin.compile-ecmascript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/validation/plugins.js:52:56:
>   [BABEL]
>   /media/martin/SSD240/dev/Proyectos-Full-Stack/proyecto-dinamo/dinamo-server-meteor/imports/client/ui/components/Page/components/Content/Content.js:
>   .**wrapped** is not a valid Plugin property    at
>   Object.keys.forEach.key
>   (/home/martin/.meteor/packages/ecmascript/.0.11.1.cvfkb8.l4wd++os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/plugin.compile-ecmascript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/validation/plugins.js:52:56)
>   at Array.forEach ()    at validatePluginObject
>   (/home/martin/.meteor/packages/ecmascript/.0.11.1.cvfkb8.l4wd++os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/plugin.compile-ecmascript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/validation/plugins.js:50:20)
>   at instantiatePlugin
>   (/home/martin/.meteor/packages/ecmascript/.0.11.1.cvfkb8.l4wd++os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/plugin.compile-ecmascript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/full.js:201:55)
>   at cachedFunction
>   (/home/martin/.meteor/packages/ecmascript/.0.11.1.cvfkb8.l4wd++os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/plugin.compile-ecmascript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/caching.js:32:19)
>   at loadPluginDescriptor
>   (/home/martin/.meteor/packages/ecmascript/.0.11.1.cvfkb8.l4wd++os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/plugin.compile-ecmascript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/full.js:192:10)
>   at config.plugins.map.descriptor
>   (/home/martin/.meteor/packages/ecmascript/.0.11.1.cvfkb8.l4wd++os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/plugin.compile-ecmascript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/full.js:68:16)
>   at Array.map ()    at recurseDescriptors
>   (/home/martin/.meteor/packages/ecmascript/.0.11.1.cvfkb8.l4wd++os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/plugin.compile-ecmascript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/full.js:67:38)
>   at recurseDescriptors
>   (/home/martin/.meteor/packages/ecmascript/.0.11.1.cvfkb8.l4wd++os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/plugin.compile-ecmascript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/full.js:86:27)
>   at loadFullConfig
>   (/home/martin/.meteor/packages/ecmascript/.0.11.1.cvfkb8.l4wd++os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/plugin.compile-ecmascript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/full.js:100:6)
>   at Object.transformSync
>   (/home/martin/.meteor/packages/ecmascript/.0.11.1.cvfkb8.l4wd++os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/plugin.compile-ecmascript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transform.js:41:38)
>   at transform
>   (/home/martin/.meteor/packages/ecmascript/.0.11.1.cvfkb8.l4wd++os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/plugin.compile-ecmascript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/meteor-babel/index.js:103:26)
>   at compile
>   (/home/martin/.meteor/packages/ecmascript/.0.11.1.cvfkb8.l4wd++os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/plugin.compile-ecmascript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/meteor-babel/index.js:113:5)
>   at Cache.Cp.get
>   (/home/martin/.meteor/packages/ecmascript/.0.11.1.cvfkb8.l4wd++os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/plugin.compile-ecmascript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/meteor-babel/cache.js:101:26)
>   at Object.exports.compile
>   (/home/martin/.meteor/packages/ecmascript/.0.11.1.cvfkb8.l4wd++os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/plugin.compile-ecmascript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/meteor-babel/index.js:51:7)
>   at Object.compile (packages/babel-compiler.js:44:29)    at
>   packages/babel-compiler.js:198:22    at Function.time
>   (/tools/tool-env/profile.js:305:10)    at profile
>   (packages/babel-compiler.js:246:20)    at
>   BabelCompiler.BCp.processOneFileForTarget
>   (packages/babel-compiler.js:197:20)    at BabelCompiler.
>   (packages/babel-compiler.js:115:26)    at Array.forEach () 
>   at BabelCompiler.BCp.processFilesForTarget
>   (packages/babel-compiler.js:114:14)
>
> ```
>    While processing files with ecmascript (for target web.browser.legacy):
> ```
>
> /home/martin/.meteor/packages/ecmascript/.0.11.1.cvfkb8.l4wd++os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/plugin.compile-ecmascript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/validation/plugins.js:52:56:
>   [BABEL]
>   /media/martin/SSD240/dev/Proyectos-Full-Stack/proyecto-dinamo/dinamo-server-meteor/imports/client/ui/components/Page/components/Content/Content.js:
>   .**wrapped** is not a valid Plugin property    at
>   Object.keys.forEach.key
>   (/home/martin/.meteor/packages/ecmascript/.0.11.1.cvfkb8.l4wd++os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/plugin.compile-ecmascript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/validation/plugins.js:52:56)
>   at Array.forEach ()    at validatePluginObject
>   (/home/martin/.meteor/packages/ecmascript/.0.11.1.cvfkb8.l4wd++os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/plugin.compile-ecmascript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/validation/plugins.js:50:20)
>   at instantiatePlugin
>   (/home/martin/.meteor/packages/ecmascript/.0.11.1.cvfkb8.l4wd++os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/plugin.compile-ecmascript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/full.js:201:55)
>   at cachedFunction
>   (/home/martin/.meteor/packages/ecmascript/.0.11.1.cvfkb8.l4wd++os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/plugin.compile-ecmascript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/caching.js:32:19)
>   at loadPluginDescriptor
>   (/home/martin/.meteor/packages/ecmascript/.0.11.1.cvfkb8.l4wd++os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/plugin.compile-ecmascript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/full.js:192:10)
>   at config.plugins.map.descriptor
>   (/home/martin/.meteor/packages/ecmascript/.0.11.1.cvfkb8.l4wd++os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/plugin.compile-ecmascript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/full.js:68:16)
>   at Array.map ()    at recurseDescriptors
>   (/home/martin/.meteor/packages/ecmascript/.0.11.1.cvfkb8.l4wd++os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/plugin.compile-ecmascript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/full.js:67:38)
>   at recurseDescriptors
>   (/home/martin/.meteor/packages/ecmascript/.0.11.1.cvfkb8.l4wd++os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/plugin.compile-ecmascript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/full.js:86:27)
>   at loadFullConfig
>   (/home/martin/.meteor/packages/ecmascript/.0.11.1.cvfkb8.l4wd++os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/plugin.compile-ecmascript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/full.js:100:6)
>   at Object.transformSync
>   (/home/martin/.meteor/packages/ecmascript/.0.11.1.cvfkb8.l4wd++os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/plugin.compile-ecmascript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transform.js:41:38)
>   at transform
>   (/home/martin/.meteor/packages/ecmascript/.0.11.1.cvfkb8.l4wd++os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/plugin.compile-ecmascript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/meteor-babel/index.js:103:26)
>   at compile
>   (/home/martin/.meteor/packages/ecmascript/.0.11.1.cvfkb8.l4wd++os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/plugin.compile-ecmascript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/meteor-babel/index.js:113:5)
>   at Cache.Cp.get
>   (/home/martin/.meteor/packages/ecmascript/.0.11.1.cvfkb8.l4wd++os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/plugin.compile-ecmascript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/meteor-babel/cache.js:101:26)
>   at Object.exports.compile
>   (/home/martin/.meteor/packages/ecmascript/.0.11.1.cvfkb8.l4wd++os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/plugin.compile-ecmascript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/meteor-babel/index.js:51:7)
>   at Object.compile (packages/babel-compiler.js:44:29)    at
>   packages/babel-compiler.js:198:22    at Function.time
>   (/tools/tool-env/profile.js:305:10)    at profile
>   (packages/babel-compiler.js:246:20)    at
>   BabelCompiler.BCp.processOneFileForTarget
>   (packages/babel-compiler.js:197:20)    at BabelCompiler.
>   (packages/babel-compiler.js:115:26)    at Array.forEach () 
>   at BabelCompiler.BCp.processFilesForTarget
>   (packages/babel-compiler.js:114:14)
>
> ```
>    While processing files with ecmascript (for target os.linux.x86_64):
> ```
>
> /home/martin/.meteor/packages/ecmascript/.0.11.1.cvfkb8.l4wd++os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/plugin.compile-ecmascript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/validation/plugins.js:52:56:
>   [BABEL]
>   /media/martin/SSD240/dev/Proyectos-Full-Stack/proyecto-dinamo/dinamo-server-meteor/imports/startup/server/accounts/custom-login-handlers/facebook-mobile-login-handler.js:
>   .**wrapped** is not a valid Plugin property    at
>   Object.keys.forEach.key
>   (/home/martin/.meteor/packages/ecmascript/.0.11.1.cvfkb8.l4wd++os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/plugin.compile-ecmascript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/validation/plugins.js:52:56)
>   at Array.forEach ()    at validatePluginObject
>   (/home/martin/.meteor/packages/ecmascript/.0.11.1.cvfkb8.l4wd++os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/plugin.compile-ecmascript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/validation/plugins.js:50:20)
>   at instantiatePlugin
>   (/home/martin/.meteor/packages/ecmascript/.0.11.1.cvfkb8.l4wd++os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/plugin.compile-ecmascript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/full.js:201:55)
>   at cachedFunction
>   (/home/martin/.meteor/packages/ecmascript/.0.11.1.cvfkb8.l4wd++os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/plugin.compile-ecmascript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/caching.js:32:19)
>   at loadPluginDescriptor
>   (/home/martin/.meteor/packages/ecmascript/.0.11.1.cvfkb8.l4wd++os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/plugin.compile-ecmascript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/full.js:192:10)
>   at config.plugins.map.descriptor
>   (/home/martin/.meteor/packages/ecmascript/.0.11.1.cvfkb8.l4wd++os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/plugin.compile-ecmascript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/full.js:68:16)
>   at Array.map ()    at recurseDescriptors
>   (/home/martin/.meteor/packages/ecmascript/.0.11.1.cvfkb8.l4wd++os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/plugin.compile-ecmascript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/full.js:67:38)
>   at recurseDescriptors
>   (/home/martin/.meteor/packages/ecmascript/.0.11.1.cvfkb8.l4wd++os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/plugin.compile-ecmascript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/full.js:86:27)
>   at loadFullConfig
>   (/home/martin/.meteor/packages/ecmascript/.0.11.1.cvfkb8.l4wd++os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/plugin.compile-ecmascript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/full.js:100:6)
>   at Object.transformSync
>   (/home/martin/.meteor/packages/ecmascript/.0.11.1.cvfkb8.l4wd++os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/plugin.compile-ecmascript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transform.js:41:38)
>   at transform
>   (/home/martin/.meteor/packages/ecmascript/.0.11.1.cvfkb8.l4wd++os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/plugin.compile-ecmascript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/meteor-babel/index.js:103:26)
>   at compile
>   (/home/martin/.meteor/packages/ecmascript/.0.11.1.cvfkb8.l4wd++os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/plugin.compile-ecmascript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/meteor-babel/index.js:113:5)
>   at Cache.Cp.get
>   (/home/martin/.meteor/packages/ecmascript/.0.11.1.cvfkb8.l4wd++os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/plugin.compile-ecmascript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/meteor-babel/cache.js:101:26)
>   at Object.exports.compile
>   (/home/martin/.meteor/packages/ecmascript/.0.11.1.cvfkb8.l4wd++os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/plugin.compile-ecmascript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/meteor-babel/index.js:51:7)
>   at Object.compile (packages/babel-compiler.js:44:29)    at
>   packages/babel-compiler.js:198:22    at Function.time
>   (/tools/tool-env/profile.js:305:10)    at profile
>   (packages/babel-compiler.js:246:20)    at
>   BabelCompiler.BCp.processOneFileForTarget
>   (packages/babel-compiler.js:197:20)    at BabelCompiler.
>   (packages/babel-compiler.js:115:26)    at Array.forEach () 
>   at BabelCompiler.BCp.processFilesForTarget
>   (packages/babel-compiler.js:114:14)
>
> => Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.

Comment: Does it help to 1.) install the npm packages with `--save`, then 2.) delete the `node_modules` and `.meteor/local` folders and 3.) run the app again?

Comment: Try reinstalling meteor.js

Comment: Nope! none of the above worked